# How does cv2.fitEllipse handle width/height with regards to rotation?

Tags: python, opencv, ellipse, data-fitting

An ellipse of width 50, height 100, and angle 0, would be identical to an ellipse of width 100, height 50, and angle 90 - i.e. one is the rotation of the other.

How does cv2.fitEllipse handle this? Does it return ellipses in some normalized form (i.e. angle is picked such that width is always < height), or can it provide any output?

I ask as I'm trying to determine whether two fit ellipses are similar, and am unsure whether I have to account for these things. The documentation doesn't address this at all.

Comment: afaik this algorithm is used: http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/1995/bmvc-95-050.pdf maybe there is additional information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see in the OpenCV source code for [fitEllipse](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp#L435) that the height of the ellipse is always larger than the width.

If the width is larger than the height, then `width` and `height` are swapped, and the `angle` is corrected. `box` is the `RotatedRect` that defines the ellipse:

```
if( box.size.width > box.size.height )
{
    float tmp;
    CV_SWAP( box.size.width, box.size.height, tmp );
    box.angle = (float)(90 + rp[4]*180/CV_PI);
}
```

Comment: I have one issue with the source code though. `box.angle` only gets set it this if-statement is executed. But outside this if-statement, it is never referenced. I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, I ran code matching thousands of ellipses, and I never got one return value where the returned width was greater than the returned height. So it seems OpenCV normalizes the ellipse such that `height >= width`.